# Does the quantmod link to yahoo stop working?

Tags: r, quantmod

I use quantmod once a week and today I got an error that I'm not used to get:

```
spy<-getSymbols(c("SPY"), src = 'google', from = '1990-01-01',  auto.assign = T)    
SPY<-cbind(SPY)
dim(SPY)


spy<-getSymbols(c("SPY"), src = 'yahoo', from = '1990-01-01',  auto.assign = T) 
**Error in download.file**(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  : 
  cannot open URL 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=SPY&a=0&b=01&c=1990&d=4&e=18&f=2017&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=SPY&x=.csv'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  :
  cannot open URL 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=SPY&a=0&b=01&c=1990&d=4&e=18&f=2017&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=SPY&x=.csv': HTTP status was '504 Maximum Transaction Time Exceeded'
```

Comment: https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/157

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referencing [this quantmod issue thread](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/157), this is a problem originating from Yahoo, and there is a fix in the development version of quantmod. Until that fix is released on CRAN, you can try installing the development version.

As described in the installation instructions in the [quantmod readme](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod#installation):

```
remotes::install_github("joshuaulrich/quantmod", ref="157_yahoo_502")
# or
devtools::install_github("joshuaulrich/quantmod", ref="157_yahoo_502")
```

Comment: Hello Michael Kirchner, after running remotes::install_github("joshuaulrich/quantmod") and devtools::install_github("joshuaulrich/quantmod")
I still get the same error. Any Idea?

Comment: Using devtools::install_github("joshuaulrich/quantmod", ref="157_yahoo_502")
I got partial data: 2612 datapoints insead 6120.
spy<-getSymbols(getSymbols(c("SPY"), src = 'yahoo', from = '1990-01-01',  auto.assign = T))
SPY<-cbind(SPY)
dim(SPY)
2612    6

Comment: You are calling `getSymbols()` inside of `getSymbols()`, ie `getSymbols(getSymbols())`. If you only use it once, you will get 6120.

Comment: Works..Thank you for your help, @Michael Kirchner.